# Python datetime subtracting date oddity

Tags: python, datetime, date, timedelta

I have a datetime object created from which I subtract 13 days as follow:

```
(date.today()-timedelta(days=13)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

The strangeness occurs when I execute the code at 6AM and 8:30AM. At 6AM, the resulting string is returned as (if today is 2012-02-29):

2012-02-15

which is 14 days before the current! However, running the same line at 8:30AM, the resulting string is returned as:

2012-02-16

Which then correct. So far I have not been able to figure out what the difference is between the small period of time. I use timezone naive datetime objects, if that is important. I would like to know what could cause this change in the resulting string date.

Many thanks.

**EDIT: (based on eumiro's suggestion below)**

datetime.datetime.now() returns:

```
>>> datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 29, 10, 46, 20, 659862)
```

And the timezone is Europe/Vienna on the server and in the django application that runs the line of code.

I also tried running a similar line to the one you suggested:

```
(pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE).localize(datetime.now(), is_dst=True) - \
    timedelta(days=13)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But with the same results... which is why I think I don't think it has much to do with timezones also. But at the same time not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 0):

You live somewhere in America? This is the place where the timezones are around 6-8 hours behind the UTC and that's the time of UTC midnight.

What does `datetime.datetime.now()` return?

If you want to get the real local time, use this (replace `"America/New_York"` with your timezone):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz

now = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.timezone("America/New_York"))
dt = (now - timedelta(days=13)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

and it should return the same correct values from midnight until midnight.

Comment: datetime.datetime.now() returns:
datetime.datetime(2012, 2, 29, 10, 46, 20, 659862)

And the timezone is Europe/Vienna on the server and in the django application that runs the line of code.

I also tried running a similar line to the one you suggested:
(pytz.timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE).localize(datetime.now(), is_dst=True)-timedelta(days=13)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

But with the same results... which is why I am very confused. Could it be the is_dst=True in the above line? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: DST issues in Austria are always within maximum two hours off UTC, so that is not the issue with apparently American timezone (6-8 hours).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately DST is poorly supported in Python.

Even pytz is not perfect, but can be made to work with hacks.

You have to decide what it means to subtract 2 days from 10th, 1p.m., either 2 calendar days or 48 hours or 172800 seconds.